# django two apps with same urls in each url's.py file

Tags: python, django

I have two apps in my django project one is "home" and other is "administrator". I am using home app for frontend of the site and administrator app for admin panel and the urls' for accessing both frontend and admin panel respectively are :-

```
www.domainname.com/home
www.domainname.com/administrator
```

**main urls.py file is :-**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/', include('home.urls')),
    url(r'^administrator/', include('administrator.urls'))
]
```

**Home's urls.py file is :-**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^sport$', views.sport, name='sport'),
    url(r'^register$', views.signup_signin, name='register'),
    url(r'^login$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^signup$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^registered-successfully$', views.registered_successfully, name='registered-successfully'),
    url(r'^logout$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^dashboard$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^create-new-event$', views.create_new_event, name='create-new-event'),
    url(r'^help$', views.help, name='help'),
    url(r'^account-settings$', views.account_settings, name='account-settings')
]
```

**Admin's urls.py file is :-**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^logout$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^dashboard$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^profile$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^edit-profile$', views.edit_profile, name='edit-profile'),
    url(r'^check-password$', views.check_password, name='check-password'),
    url(r'^help$', views.faq_management, name='help')
]
```

As you can check that there are some common url's in both app's file, like index, dashboard, logout help.

These urls are creating problem if i link them in href, for example if i link "help" url in frontend using

```
<a href="{% url 'help' %}" >
```

It tries to redirect me to admin panel's help url, and if i change the order of apps in main urls.py file than vice versa problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a namespace to your urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/', include('home.urls', namespace='home')),
    url(r'^administrator/', include('administrator.urls', namespace='admin'))
]
```

Then you can access them like:

```
<a href="{% url 'home:help' %}" >
<a href="{% url 'admin:help' %}" >
```

Comment: Using namespace i have to change links in my complete project, i know that this can resolve my problem, but is there any othere solution for this ?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know any other way.

Comment: Maybe you can add the namespace for only one of the url patterns. This will at least reduce the no. of places you have to change the url.